# I use a argument and then an if statement that works, the second if statement for that same argument doesn't work.

Tags: vb.net

```
    Console.WriteLine("Would you like to administer the program?")
    Dim answer1 As String = Nothing

    If Console.ReadLine = "yes" Then
        Console.WriteLine("ok. that's the spirit!")

    End If

        If Console.ReadLine = "no" Then
        Console.WriteLine("ok")

    End If
```

why does the second if statement not work?

should I include something else for the second if statement?

Comment: What do you mean it doesn't work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are trying to read the console twice, thus the second time it is different. Store the Console.ReadLine into variable and check it

```
Console.WriteLine("Would you like to administer the program?")
Dim answer1 As String = Console.ReadLine

If answer1 = "yes" Then
    Console.WriteLine("ok. that's the spirit!")

End If

If answer1 = "no" Then
    Console.WriteLine("ok")
End If
```

Or use switch...

Answer (score 0):

Unclear question? What does not work? try this;

```
    Console.WriteLine("Would you like to administer the program?")

      Select Case Console.ReadLine.ToLower
            Case "yes"
                 Console.WriteLine("ok. that's the spirit!")

            Case "no"
                 Console.WriteLine("ok")

            Case else
               ' Do nothing
        End Select
```